# Oracle scheduler JOBS: get argument_value used in a specific job instance

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle Scheduler Job configured in my DB 19c. This is as event-based job, with a queue table created used in this process.

I need to analyse a possible problem in one of this executions. In `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG` table I have the instance and a JOB_SUBNAME called `SCHED$_EVTPARINST_89121`.

Although I don't have DBA privileges, I have two questions:

- How can I get the parameters values passed to this scheduler Job instance?
- How can I get the Log (history) of enqueue messages, with enqueue date and `set_job_argument_value` associated to each enqueue message?

I've tried to check in Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-E9B234FF-C7F3-44B0-AEC8-A997353C414F or https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_aq.htm#ARPLS004) without success.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you back up and share what you're trying to accomplish at a higher level? You may be asking for details that are unnecessary because there is probably a better way to do what you need done.